# How to modify inherited properties of parent class in child class using python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, tkinter

I have a child class which has inherited from parent class. I want to modify and omit some init properties of parent class when calling from child class.However, i am not able to override the properties.
Following is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class firstClass:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.master = root
        self.master.geometry("680x600+450+200") 
        self.master.title("WINDOW 1")
        self.statusbar          = tk.Label (self.master, text = "MAIN MENU",font='Times 10',relief ="sunken",anchor=W) 
        self.statusbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X) 
        self.button             = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Button", command=self.createNewWindow,bg="peach puff",borderwidth= 2,bd=2,font="Times 12",relief ="raised")
        self.button.place(width=160,    height=50, x=20, y=55) 
        self.button1             = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Dummy Button", command=self.doesNothing,bg="peach puff",borderwidth= 2,bd=2,font="Times 12",relief ="raised")
        self.button1.place(width=160,    height=50, x=20, y=170) 

    def doesNothing(self):
        pass
                
class secondClass(firstClass):
    def __init__(self,root):
        super().__init__(root) 
        
    def createNewWindow(self):
        self.newWindow          = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app                = thirdClassMain(self.newWindow)
        
class thirdClassMain(firstClass):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master) 
        self.top                = master
        self.top.title("WINDOW 2")
        self.button             = tk.Button(self.top, text = "New1 Button", command=self.createNewWindow,bg="peach puff",borderwidth= 2,bd=2,font="Times 12",relief ="raised")
        self.button.place(width=160,   height=50, x=20, y=305)
        self.statusbar          = tk.Label (self.top, text = "New1 MENU",font='Times 10',relief ="sunken",anchor=W) 
        self.statusbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X) 

    def createNewWindow(self):
        self.newWindow          = tk.Toplevel(self.top)
        self.app                = fourthClassMain(self.newWindow)


class fourthClassMain(firstClass):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master) 
        self.statusbar          = tk.Label (self.master, text = "New2 MENU",font='Times 10',relief ="sunken",anchor=W) 
        self.statusbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X) 
        self.master.title("WINDOW 3")

        
    def createNewWindow(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    secondClass = secondClass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Error:

1. Pop up Window 2 should only contain "New1 Button" but it contains all the buttons from parent class
2. Pop up Window 2 modify title of menu should be only "New1 MENU". It should not create a separate title as can be seen from the code
3. Window 3 should contain only "Dummy Button". How can i delete "Button"?

Is this not possible??

From all the above points,it is clear that I am missing the underlying concept of inheritance and how to modify the parent properties.
Please guide me.
Thank you

Any answers or guide?I have been waiting for so long for some response

Comment: Try removing `super().__init__(master)` from `thirdClassMain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


class FirstClass:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.master.geometry("680x600+450+200")
        self.master.title("WINDOW 1")
        self.statusbar = tk.Label(self.master, text="MAIN MENU")
        self.statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Button", command=self.create_new_window)
        self.button.place(width=160, height=50, x=20, y=55)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text="Dummy Button", command=self.does_nothing)
        self.button1.place(width=160, height=50, x=20, y=170)

    def does_nothing(self):
        pass


class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        
    def create_new_window(self):
        self.new_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.new_window.geometry("680x600+450+200")
        self.app = ThirdClassMain(self.new_window)


class ThirdClassMain(FirstClass):
    def __init__(self, master):
        # You don't always need to call the `FirstClass`'s constuctor if you don't want
        #super().__init__(master)
        self.top = master
        self.top.title("WINDOW 2")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.top, text="New1 Button", command=self.create_new_window)
        self.button.place(width=160, height=50, x=20, y=305)
        self.statusbar = tk.Label(self.top, text="New1 MENU")
        self.statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    def create_new_window(self):
        self.new_window = tk.Toplevel(self.top)
        self.new_window.geometry("680x600+450+200")
        self.app = FourthClassMain(self.new_window)


class FourthClassMain(FirstClass):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        # We aren't going to create a new label but we are going to update
        # The already existing one
        self.statusbar.config(text="New2 MENU")
        self.master.title("WINDOW 3")
        # Destroy the button that you don't need
        self.button.destroy()

    def create_new_window(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    second_class = SecondClass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am not exactly sure if this is what you need but I think I covered all of the issues you had. I also renamed some of your variable to make it more pythonic. You had a lot of white spaces for no reason which is generally discouraged.

**Edit**

The code but with the binding:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


class ToplevelFollower(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        super().bind("<Configure>", self.move)
        self.move()

    def move(self, event=None):
        w, h = super().winfo_width(), super().winfo_height()
        x, y = super().winfo_rootx(), super().winfo_rooty()
        x -= 8
        y -= 30
        self.master.geometry("%ix%i+%i+%i" % (w, h, x, y))


class FirstClass:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.master.geometry("680x600")#+450+200
        self.master.title("WINDOW 1")
        self.statusbar = tk.Label(self.master, text="MAIN MENU")
        self.statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Button", command=self.create_new_window)
        self.button.place(width=160, height=50, x=20, y=55)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text="Dummy Button", command=self.does_nothing)
        self.button1.place(width=160, height=50, x=20, y=170)

    def does_nothing(self):
        pass


class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        root.geometry("680x600+450+200")

    def create_new_window(self):
        self.new_window = ToplevelFollower(self.master)
        self.new_window.geometry("680x600")#+450+200
        self.app = ThirdClassMain(self.new_window)


class ThirdClassMain(FirstClass):
    def __init__(self, master):
        # You don't always need to call the `FirstClass`'s constuctor if you don't want
        #super().__init__(master)
        self.top = master
        self.top.title("WINDOW 2")
        self.button = tk.Button(self.top, text="New1 Button", command=self.create_new_window)
        self.button.place(width=160, height=50, x=20, y=305)
        self.statusbar = tk.Label(self.top, text="New1 MENU")
        self.statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    def create_new_window(self):
        self.new_window = ToplevelFollower(self.top)
        self.new_window.geometry("680x600")#+450+200
        self.app = FourthClassMain(self.new_window)


class FourthClassMain(FirstClass):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        # We aren't going to create a new label but we are going to update
        # The already existing one
        self.statusbar.config(text="New2 MENU")
        self.master.title("WINDOW 3")
        # Destroy the button that you don't need
        self.button.destroy()

    def create_new_window(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    second_class = SecondClass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

There still is a problem with it: it binks when a new window is created but that will be difficult to fix.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The answer was clear and precise. 
I have an additional question. With the current method, I have multiple windows. If i move one of the window, the previous window shows up. Is there a way to stitch up the new windows?So that if i move one window all the previous windows moves together. I would really appreciate your response. Thank you

Comment: @codeheadache you will have to bind to `"<Configure>"` and use: `second_root.geometry("%ix%i+%i+%i" % (main_root.winfo_width(), main_root.winfo_height(), main_root.winfo_rootx(), main_root.winfo_rooty()))`. `<Configure>` is called when the root is resized/moved. The second piece of code will move the window over the other one.

Comment: Will it be possible to edit your code to include your suggestion on binding?

Comment: @codeheadache I edited my answer. Tell me if you need me to add anything more to it.

Comment: Thank you for helping above and beyond what I was looking for.